where is happening the triple fault?
On my OS, I think a triple fault is happening. I will only show the part (boot.asm) where the triple fault is occurring.
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

start:
    cli
    xor ax, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00
    sti

    mov si, boot_message
    call print_string

    mov bx, 0x1000
    mov dh, 0x02
    mov dl, 0x00
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x0000
    mov ah, 0x02
    int 0x13

    mov si, kernel_loaded_message
    call print_string

    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E
.next_char:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 0x10
    jmp .next_char
.done:
    ret

[BITS 32]
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov esp, 0x9C00

    mov si, protected_mode_message
    call print_string

    jmp KERNEL_SEG:start

boot_message db 'Bootloader started', 0
kernel_loaded_message db 'Kernel loaded', 0
protected_mode_message db 'Protected mode', 0

gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    dd 0x00000000
    dd 0x00000000

gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x00

gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x00

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
KERNEL_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

I’m using NASM. Sorry if the answer is straightforward or if I’m asking something dumb. I’m not experienced with OS development, and it’s my first time doing a bootloader and kernel on my own.
I tried editing some parts of boot.asm, but none worked. Also, QEMU with the option -d int -no-reboot
SMM: enter
EAX=00000001 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=000f246b ESP=00006ce0
EIP=000eae06 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000080 CCD=00000001 CCO=LOGICB
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=00000001 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=000f246b ESP=00006ce0
EIP=000eae06 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=00006cff
ESI=00006c80 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006c40 ESP=00006c40
EIP=00007dc8 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006c40 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=00006cff
ESI=00006c80 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006c40 ESP=00006c40
EIP=000f7dc9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=07fa91e0
ESI=000e9f80 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006c40 ESP=00006c40
EIP=000f7de2 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006c2c CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=07fa91e0
ESI=000e9f80 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006c40 ESP=00006c40
EIP=00007de3 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000696a EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=00007dc8 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000692a CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000696a EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=000f7dc9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=000f7de2 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00006916 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=00007de3 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006964 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=00007dc8 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00006924 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006964 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=000f7dc9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07f8f5b0 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=000f7de2 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00006910 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07f8f5b0 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=00007de3 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000696a EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=00007dc8 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000692a CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000696a EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=000f7dc9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=000f7de2 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00006916 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=0000692a ESP=0000692a
EIP=00007de3 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006964 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=00007dc8 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00006924 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7dc9 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006964 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=000f7dc9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07ecf5b0 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=000f7de2 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f62c0 00000037
IDT=     000f62fe 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00006910 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007de3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07ecf5b0 EDI=07fbec5e EBP=00006924 ESP=00006924
EIP=00007de3 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db00 000db000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
     0: v=10 e=0000 i=1 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000007c41 pc=0000000000007c41 SP=0010:0000000000009bfc env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000e50
EAX=00000e50 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000200
ESI=00007c8b EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00009bfc
EIP=00007c41 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c99 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000e50 CCO=SUBB
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     1: v=0d e=0082 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000007c41 pc=0000000000007c41 SP=0010:0000000000009bfc env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000e50
EAX=00000e50 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000200
ESI=00007c8b EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00009bfc
EIP=00007c41 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c99 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000e50 CCO=SUBB
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     2: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000007c41 pc=0000000000007c41 SP=0010:0000000000009bfc env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000e50
EAX=00000e50 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000200
ESI=00007c8b EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00009bfc
EIP=00007c41 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c99 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000  
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000e50 CCO=SUBB
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd


You can't use print_string from protected mode because it invokes int 0x10. For future reference, note that the qemu log points out the faulting instruction for you: EIP=00007c41

Moreover, print_string is 16 bit code and called be called from 32-bit code.

@AndreyTurkin probably by sheer coincidence it encodes the same instructions in 32 bit mode too so it would work if it wasn't for the int 0x10.

right. No word-sized immediates, all jumps are 8-bit relatives so it happens to be sane when decoded as 32-bit. Still, it is 16-bit assembly and should be treated that way.
